# String to integer array in MATLAB GUIDE

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, integer, matlab-guide

I'm working with GUIDE on MATLAB. In my GUI, there is a text field in which the user is to enter an array of numbers. How can I convert this into a form that can be used to perform calculations? Basically my question is how can a string like "[1 1 1]" be converted into an array? (I'm working with integers from the range of 0-360 so string-'0' doesn't work for me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
 a = str2num('[1 1 1]')
```

Not sure what you meen by "string-'0' doesn't work for me" though.

Comment: This works for me, thanks for your help!
What I meant was when I execute b='[90 90 90]'-'0' for example I get 9 0 9 0 9 0 as an output. I needed something to keep it as 90.